# SQL Server CE can't parse my query (Insert and then select)

Tags: sql-server-ce

I get this error when I run my query:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 157,Token in error = SELECT ]

This is exactly what I would use when writing something while using 2008 R2...

Here is the query:

```
INSERT INTO tblExample([Example], [GroupID], [Key], [Value], [ExpectedColumn]) 
VALUES (@Example, @GroupID, @k, @v, @ExpectedColumn);
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

The execution:

```
if (db == null) { throw new Exception("You must give me an actiavted DBCon!"); }
object ret = null;
db.Command.CommandText = query;
AddParameters(db.Command, parameters);

if (db.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    db.Connection.Open();

var temp = db.Command.ExecuteScalar();
if (temp != null && temp != DBNull.Value)
{
    ret = temp;
}
return ret;
```

Comment: It almost looks like it id not like the tagged on 2nd SQL command `SELECT @@Identity`. Which interface are you using? Is there possibly a limitation to single SQL commands?

Comment: I believe SQL Server CE doesn't support multiple SQL statements in a single command - I tried to have multiple `INSERT` in a single command, but that never worked, either.

Comment: Im using like, exactly what I would use on the server except its been slightly modified for ce

Comment: Added the code where it gets executed.